# to remove stickiness of a header in mobile device

Tags: jquery, css

I am stuck at a place. I want to remove stickiness of a header in mobile device,while it should remain intact in bigger screens. what I have tried so far is this, but this is on the basis of top scroll and causing problem.I am novice in jquery, and so far able to paste this script from internet to my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastScrollTop = 0;  
    var st; 
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(event)
    {       
         st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
         if (st == 0)       
         {                 
             jQuery(".main-header").removeClass("sticky-head");        
             jQuery('.main-header').stop().animate({top:'0px'},1000);
             jQuery('.main-header').css("height", 135);     
         }      
         else if (st > lastScrollTop || st < lastScrollTop)
         {              
             jQuery(".main-header").addClass("sticky-head");            
             jQuery('.main-header').stop().animate({top:'-75px'},900);          
             jQuery('.main-header').css("height", 140);     
         } 
         else 
         {                  
             jQuery('.main-header').stop().animate({top:'-75px'},1000);     
         }      
         lastScrollTop = st;    
    });            
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check for mobile devices on scroll and `return` if `true` as below

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(event)
{       
     if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        return;//just get out from this event
     } //check if this is a mobile device

     st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
     if (st == 0)       
     {                 
         jQuery(".main-header").removeClass("sticky-head");        
         jQuery('.main-header').stop().animate({top:'0px'},1000);
         jQuery('.main-header').css("height", 135);     
     }      
     else if (st > lastScrollTop || st < lastScrollTop)
     {              
         jQuery(".main-header").addClass("sticky-head");            
         jQuery('.main-header').stop().animate({top:'-75px'},900);          
         jQuery('.main-header').css("height", 140);     
     } 
     else 
     {                  
         jQuery('.main-header').stop().animate({top:'-75px'},1000);     
     }      
     lastScrollTop = st;    
});
```

Comment: thanks  a lot. you are my day saviour. wish i was able to upvote you but unfortunately not. but (y) from my side :):)

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you atlesat.. :)

Comment: @santoshbawari.. Accepting in the sense click a right mark below upvote/downvote button.. :) and I think you haven't done that.. :)

Comment: i have buit i need atleast 15 reputation for it, which i dont have right now

Comment: I don't think so!! Anyways!! Its ok!! Glad it helped!! :)